# Trading clipboard contents between phone and computer

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, sync, windows, copy-paste

Is there a way to send information on my phone (for example, an SMS that I started to type, that got way too long, and that I decided I want on my computer to send as an email instead) through the clipboard? There are ways like sending myself emails, but they're not exactly great, on top of me finding absolutely no decent way of using email on my phone.

In an ideal world, on my phone, I would like to have a "right-click" (hold-the-tap) option, "Send to PC", and if Wi-Fi is enabled, I would just go to my PC, perhaps authorise the received clipboard (not sure that would be necessary or convenient), and then just Ctrl-V somewhere, and voilà, it pastes what came from my phone in my browser/Skype conversation/Word document/etc.

Also, I would very much like a similar option to go the other way. To send things typed from my computer to my Android device. In an ideal world, through a right-click option called "Send to Phone", or even a keyboard shortcut like ctrl-alt-shift-C. But this part, I'm not sure if it wouldn't belong on SuperUser more.

My PC uses Windows 8. My phone runs 2.3.6 Gingerbread.

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Q (SGH-T589W).

For your information, this is almost the same phone as the Samsung Gravity Smart. Or literally the same phone. These dual names confuse me.

Samsung Kies does NOT work for me, so no use mentioning it (unless you can make it work unlike the Samsung support people I contacted, but this would belong in another question).

Answer (score 5):

If all you care about is the clipboard sharing, you might want to take a look at [ClipSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.bdwm.clipsync). This app allows you to share your clipboard between multiple Android devices and your Windows PC: Copy on one device, and it appears in the clipboard of all others. At least that's what the app description says (all Windows I have are just for fresh air and light coming in, or to look out of them (not Out-look), so I cannot verify). A 4.5 star rating suggests it works -- and it's only 150kB "big".

If you want a bigger benefit, take [Compro01's advice](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/37346/16575) and have a look at [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). It's a great app, and lets you maintain your Android device from any web browser in the same WiFi network really nice (edit your contacts, write SMS, browse pics...). An beside that, allows for clipboard sharing.

Comment: I think I'll be trying your option first. Large apps with more options than I need, I try to avoid those on my small phone memory.

Comment: Yepp, thought so (your phone is quite small on resources) -- that's why I put that even though the other answer included your option. But Airdroid is rather big in size (3,7M compared to 150k) -- no use for rockets to kill a fly :)

Comment: Does either option encrypt end-to-end?  A primary use case for me would be copying passwords.

Comment: No idea, @KevinS – if it's not in the app description, you will have to ask the dev.

Comment: @Izzy I'm struggling to set up Clipsync between my smartphone and tablet (both android) is this feasable? Or I should try something along the lines of Tasker?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I've tried neither yet, so I cannot tell (I vaguely remember having played a bit with this idea about 5 years ago, but no details anymore). Have you checked my list of [Clipboard Tools](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard)? Has a secial section for this.

Comment: @Izzy thanks I will try and let you know the best I find

Comment: @xavier_fakerat in no case let us know what you found. Beware, you could be tempted to write an answer! #D

Answer (score 2):

[Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) will allow for bidirectional clipboard sharing (not sure if it will work if you copy, then fire up airdroid or not though), as well as general remote control the device.

Answer (score 0):

Craig's UDP Clipboard Share!

Turn your Android Clipboards into one! share between android and windows devices, copy from one device paste from any other device also running the clipboard!

No internet required!
Windows app contained in the apk!
Simply install and run, no configuration!
Notification of arrival!
Launch youtube videos on tv boxes!

Easiest clipboard text sync tool out!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=share.clipboard.craigs.craigsclipboardshare